# How to get result of numpy.logspace() as a column in single line of code?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say that I would like to have array of 10 logarithmically spaced values with shape (10,1), using numpy.logspace(). Is there any way to create it in single line of code?
`np.logspace(np.log10(1),np.log10(10),10).shape` gives shape (10,).

If there is any way to do it I would like to avoid assigning result of numpy.logspace() to some variable and changing the shape afterwards.

- I didn't find anything about in [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) of logspace.
- Transposition works for arrays with more than 1 dimension.

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
In [3]: np.logspace(np.log10(1), np.log10(10), 10).reshape((10, 1))
Out[3]: 
array([[  1.        ],
       [  1.29154967],
       [  1.66810054],
       [  2.15443469],
       [  2.7825594 ],
       [  3.59381366],
       [  4.64158883],
       [  5.9948425 ],
       [  7.74263683],
       [ 10.        ]])
```